# Error while running etcd v3 on Docker

Tags: docker, etcd, etcd3

When I try to run etcd (version 3.0.0) on Docker:

```
sudo docker run -d -v /usr/share/ca-certificates/:/etc/ssl/certs -p 4001:4001 -p 2380:2380 -p 2379:2379 \
 --name etcd quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.0.0  \
 -name etcd0 \
 -advertise-client-urls http://${HostIP}:2379,http://${HostIP}:4001 \
 -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001 \
 -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://${HostIP}:2380 \
 -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
 -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
 -initial-cluster etcd0=http://${HostIP}:2380 \
 -initial-cluster-state new
```

I have an error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"-name\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n".`

What is the reason of this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: not a programming,but a docker admin problem, sorry, off-topic imho.

Comment: Seems, the image does not have an `ENTRYPOINT` defined and tries to run the command `-name` which is of course not found.

Comment: In etcd v3 the Docker interface changed so that one needs to give the starting command if one wishes to give parameters. This is so that the image could be used also for running e.g. the etcdctl command line tool. See my repo for samples that work: https://github.com/akauppi/etcd3-bench/blob/master/docs/Running%20etcd%20manually.md

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the [quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.0.0](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/v3.0.0/Dockerfile-release) image does not contain an `ENTRYPOINT`, instead opting for `CMD`.  So, if you want to supply all the arguments on the `docker run` you will need to specify the command as well:

```
docker run -p 2379:2379 --name etcd quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.1.0 \
    /usr/local/bin/etcd \
        --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 \
        --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 \
        --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
        --listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
        --initial-cluster "default=http://0.0.0.0:2380"
```